# Cordova Text To Speech not speaking

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, text-to-speech

I am trying to build a test Text To speech function for my app using the cordova plugin.

I have added the cordova.js file, and the tts.js fil and installed the cordova Text to speech plugin, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-texttospeech

I have used the following code for the example

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
// basic usage
TTS
    .speak('hello, world!').then(function () {
        alert('success');
    }, function (reason) {
        alert(reason);
    });


}, false);
```

But nothing is happening, have i missed something?

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772934/speech-recognition-plugin-not-working-in-cordova-6/37808638#37808638

Comment: I have seen that and tried the solution there, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Cordova media plugin is added?

Comment: Any stack trace could you see while debugging?